# Как правильно удалить Android Studio бета?

Tags: windows, android-studio

Сейчас у меня на компьютере установлено две версии Android Studio: AS 2.3.3 и AS 3.0 Beta 7. Как правильно анинсталлировать Android Studio бета версии? Будет ли достаточно просто удалить папку или же нужны какие-либо ещё действия (удалить что-либо из реестра и т.п.)?

Comment: судя по слову `реестр` - речь про windows?

Comment: @Grundy, да, ОС - windows

Comment: А разве у студии нет uninstall?

Comment: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39953495/2881286)

Comment: Не уверен есть ли какие-то отличия для beta или нет

Comment: @Grundy, для beta-версии нету. Это вроде как специально было сделано, чтобы на одном компьютере можно было и старую стабильную версию оставить, и пользоваться бета-версией

Comment: Ну в любом случае, если есть uninstall - То лучше начать с него